# Install enchant C library in ProQuest' TDM Studio (which use an AWS SageMaker server)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, c-libraries, enchant

Im in trouble installing Install enchant C library in AWS SageMaker.
I follow these steps (I sent the commands from jupyter-notebook -in python language- to terminal using os.system, and os.popen -for got outputs of terminal-  ):

(1st) Ask for "enchant C library" repo:

```
os.propen("yum whatprovides enchant")
```

The anwser of previous snippet is:

```
Loaded plugins: dkms-build-requieres, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper,
            : versionlock
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://repo.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list error was 14: HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://repo.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list error was 14: HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden
1:enchant-1.6.0-5.2.amzn1.i686 : An Enchanting Spell Checking Library
Repo   : amzn-main
1:enchant-1.6.0-5.2.amzn1.x86_64 : An Enchanting Spell Checking Library
Repo   : amzn-main
```

(2nd) Install enchant-1.6.0-5.2.amzn1.x86_64 package:

```
os.popen( "sudo yum install enchant -y" )
```

The anwser of previous snippet is:

```
Loaded plugins: dkms-build-requieres, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper,
            : versionlock
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://repo.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list error was 14: HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://repo.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/latest/main/mirror.list error was 14: HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package enchant.x86_64 1:1.6.0-5.2.amzn1 will be installed
--> Proecssing Dependecy: libhunspell-1.2.so.0()(64bit) for package: 1:enchant-1.6.0-5.2.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package hunspell.x86_64 0:1.2.8-16.2.amzn1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved
enter code here
=======================================================================
Package              Arch      Version            Repository     Size
=======================================================================
Installing:
enchant             x86_64    1:1.6.0-5.2.amzn1   amzn-main        54 k
Instanlling for dependencies:
hunspell            x86_64    1:1.8-16.2.amzn1    amzn-main       191 k

Transaction Summary
=======================================================================
Install 1 Package (+1 Denpendet package)

Total download size: 245 k
Installed size: 514 k
Downloading packages:
```

So, the last step would be enough to install enchant C library but when I try to import enchant in python I get the follow output:

```
import enchant
-------------------------------------------
Import Error: The 'enchant' C library was not found and maybe needs to be installed.
See https://pyenchant.github.io/pyenchant/install.html
for details
```

Comment: I will grant you that error message is...not good, but you need to install the [python bindings for enchant](https://pypi.org/project/pyenchant/) with pip, in addition to the system lib via yum.

Comment: I installed pyenchant  package ( `!{sys.executable} -m pip install pyenchant` ), and the suppose "the enchant C library" that I would install -in the step that I shown- is not really the C library??

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, the steps followed are correct (for install enchant package), the problem was that the server have not access to repos, so there was not possible to download packages.
The reason is that (a detail that I omitted in my question: I was working in an aws server through ProQuest's TDM Studio) the server just donwload packages from Anaconda or PyPI Repositories.